# Why is $\{0\}$ not open in $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My teacher said that $\{0\}$ is not open in $[0,1]$. Why is this true?

Comment: You need to elaborate - what is the topology on $[0,1]$? For example, $\{0\}$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$ with the discrete topology.

Comment: You need to explain what meaning you have been given for "open", since answers and comments already suggest different starting points.

Comment: @MarkBennet, My teacher said it after proving that discrete topology on nonempty set $X$ is not path connected.

Comment: What is the topology on $[0,1]$? The subspace topology of the real line?

Comment: Because for any $1>r>0$ and any $x\in \{0\} $ then $\{y:|y-x| <r\}=\{y:|y-0|<r\}=(-r,r)\cap [0,1]=[0,r)\not \subset \{0\} $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which topology are you considering. Actually $\{0\}$ it is *open* in $[0,1]$ endowed with the discrete topology.

But I guess you are considering $[0, 1]$ with the usual topology induced by the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

The induced topology $\tau$ on $[0,1]$ is defined as follows:
$$
\tau \,\,\colon = \{A \cap[0,1] : A \text{ is open in } \mathbb{R} \}.
$$

Therefore if $\{0\}$ was open, there must be an open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ (open in the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$) such that $\{0\} = A \cap [0,1]$. Can you see why this leads to a contradiction?

Comment: No, I can't see it. Why does it lead to contradiction?

Comment: Since the family of open intervals is a base for the topology of $\mathbb{R}$, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $A$ is an open interval, i.e. $A = (a, b)$ for some reals $a < b$. 
Now if $b \le 0$, $A \cap [0,1] $ is empty. If $b > 0$, then $A \cap [0,1] = [0, b)$. So in any case, $A \cap [0,1]  \ne \{0\}$.

Comment: What open set  A in R is such that A $\cap $ [0,1] = {0}?  A must contain 0 but it can't contain anything imediately larger than 0.  So either it contains (r,0] and nothing immediately above 0.  Or it contains {0} and nothing immediately above or below zero.  Neither of those sets can be open in R.

Answer (score 0):

An open set should necessarily contain at least one interval. This is not the case here.

Comment: What about the empty set?

Comment: Not entirely true.  If X={0} $\cup [1,3) $ then{0} IS open in X.

Comment: @fleablood, our space was connected.

Comment: You didn't say in "our space".  You said "necessarily".  And if you specifically meant specifically the space [0,1] then you should have explained why.  It's not particularly any more obvious to me that a non-empty open set in connected space must contain an interval then it is obvious that {0} just doesn't "look" open.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's complement is not closed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/793621)

Comment: @JaideepKhare   You are wrong.  It exactly answers the question.  Not only that, it points how to write the proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a topology question. We assume the usual topology on the real line (that is, the open sets are every open interval $(a,b) \subset[0,1]$, the intervals $(0,1]$, $[0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ and the empty set.

Why isn't $\{0\}$ open then? Remember that closed sets are every set whose complement is open. Since the complement of $\{0\}$ in $[0,1]$ is $(0,1]$, which we defined as an open set, then $\{0\}$ is closed.

Comment: Ok, so $\{0\}$ is closed. However, are you sure that this definitely excludes the possibility that it's also open? As far as I understand, the two are not mutually exclusive

Comment: Well, to be open would require that the complement (0,1] is closed.  Is it?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume the metric space definition of open (and the euclidean real metric) that is:

$A $ is open if every point of $A $ has a neighborhood that is completely contained in $A $.

Or more formally:

$A\subset X$ is open if for every point $x\in A $ there exists an $r > 0$ so that the neighborhood $B_r (x) =\{y\in X|d (x,y)<r \}=\{y\in X :|x-y| <r\}(x-r,x+r)\cap X \subset A $.

That is not the case fo $A=\{0\} $ and $X=[0,1] $. If $x\in A $ then $x=0$.  And for *any* $r $ so that $0 <r <1$ then $B_r (0)=[0,r) \not \subset \{0\} $.  And for any $r \ge 1$, $B_r (0)=[0,1]\not \subset \{0\} $.

So *no* neighborhood of zero is contained completely in $A $.  So $A $ isn't open.

===

Alternative:  the open sets in $\mathbb R$ are the open intervals $(a,b) $ and the unions of such open intervals.

So the open sets in $[0,1] $, will be the open intervals $(a,b) $ intersected with $[0,1] $ and unions of such intervals intersected with $[0,1] $.

These are the intervals: $(a,b)$ where $0 <a <b <1$, $(a,1]$ where $0 <a <1$, $[0,b)$ where $0 <b <1$, $[0,1] $, and any union of these. (Oh, and the empty set.)

$\{0\} $ is not any of these nor is it a union of any of these.

$(a,b)\not \subset \{0\}$; $[0,b)\not \subset \{0\}; (a,1]\not \subset \{0\}; [0,1] \not \subset \{0\}$.

So it isn't open.